# NodeJS on a Raspberry Pi with a soundcard

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi

I'm currently working on an art project where I need to play audio,wav files (can be converted if needed) on 6 seperate audio channels.
The project will run on a Raspberry Pi with a GigaPort HD+ Sounddevice.
I've got it working with PureData Extended ( Max7 -ish program that can run on Linux).

But I prefer to have a NodeJS server doing everything, but the problem is that I just can't find a package for NodeJS to do this? / The ones i found like speaker (https://www.npmjs.com/package/speaker) gives me a errors while trying to install it.

I really need it to play audio files simultaneous on different channels.

Anyone have any idea which package to use or anything else that can help me.

Comment: update to show copy N paste of the output from your install commands  `sudo apt-get install libasound2-dev`  and  `npm install speaker -g` ... also which PI are you using ?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/8HUZWHhM   pastebin of npm install Speaker -g on my Windows 10 laptop. I'm currently trying to code it on here before switching to Pi

Comment: just a guess as I'm on a ubuntu laptop however as per the npm doc try to pick audio backend by running  `npm install speaker -g  --mpg123-backend=win32`   ...  if still a no go next I would see if its underlying package installs OK   `npm i mpg123n`

Comment: if still errors I would bite the bullet , backup all essential files, install linux (ubuntu 18.04 ) or at very least do your development on your own cloud server for $4 per month https://www.ovh.com/world/vps/

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'm currently working on the Rpi and it seems that here I can install the speaker npm without the error. Now I just need to find a way to tell it to play "x.mp3" on one of the channels instead of all of them

Comment: 'Update' , it runs on the Raspberry Pi. Just struggling to get it to work with my soundcard and need to be able to "choose" which channel. Opened an " issue" on the github, let's hope they can help

Answer (score 0):

To build this module for the RPi you need to clone the source code from GitHub into your node_modules directory. Once there you can build it by specifying the OS and target_arch variable with node-gyp configure. When the config is complete you can build the source.

```
git clone https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-speaker.git
cd node-speaker
node-gyp configure --OS=linux --target-arch=arm
node-gyp build
cd ../..
```

You then need to manually install the dependancies of the node-speaker module.

```
npm install bindings debug buffer-alloc
```

You should then be able to run the example and hear a 2 second 440hz tone through your speakers.

```
node node_modules/node-speaker/examples/sine.js
```